# Como fazer validação de cep para Android

Tags: java, android, api, mobile, cep

Gostaria de saber como faço a validação de um cep digitado pelo usuário em um EditText no Android. Preciso de alguma API específica? Quero validar se o cep é existente e retornar na tela se não for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você tiver a fórmula para validar o CEP em mãos, você pode fazer isso na classe.

Capture o texto dela usando

`TextView  textoCEP = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.<suaEditText>);`

Então, coloque em uma `String` aquele texto capturando-o com um `<sua editText>.getText();`
Pode ser que precisa usar `.toString();` porque elas costumam retornar `CharSequences`.

Se não for isso, é algo bem nessa linha. Espero poder te ajudar.

**EDIT:**
Então, Validar CEPs é meio complicado. Você pode checar se o cep tem o número certo de dígitos, que são 8, e formatá-lo usando um `substring` (Visto na internet/não testado):

```
        if (cep.Length == 8) {
            cep = cep.Substring(0, 5) + "-" + cep.Substring(5, 3);
        }
```

Porém, os três dígitos finais indicam o estado de onde aquele CEP provém. Como seria muito grande colar todos os números aqui, segue algo parecido num fórum que vi no Google. Não está em Java, mas você deve conseguir pegar a ideia:
http://www.devmedia.com.br/dicas-validando-cep/833

Comment: Fazer o cast de uma ```EditText``` para uma ```TextView``` funciona, pois ambas usam textos.

Comment: O que eu não tenho é justamente o código de validação. Queria saber se era por api dos correios ou algo assim.

Comment: @FelipeMiranda, Editei minha resposta. Espero que seja o que busque.

Comment: Obrigado! É isso que eu busco, mas quero ver se ele é um cep existente também. Vou analisar o link que me mandou.

Comment: @FelipeMiranda, se minha resposta ajudou, marque-a depois. Mas, se a resposta foi algo diferente do que eu falei e você encontrou, responda sua própria pergunta, assim outros usuários do SOpt podem ter certeza! Abraço.

Comment: Cara, não consigo usar o método substring. Lembrando que eu estou pegando o cep de um EditText que o usuário informa.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar essa [classe](https://github.com/viniciuspetrachin/ValidateFields-for-Android/) disponível no GitHub como projeto exemplo.

```
String zipcode = editText.getText().toString();
    Pattern pattern_zipcode = Pattern.compile("(^\\d{5}-\\d{3}|^\\d{2}.\\d{3}-\\d{3}|\\d{8})");
    Matcher matcher = pattern_zipcode.matcher(zipcode);
    if(zipcode.equals("")){
        editText.setError("O campo não pode estar vazio");
        editText.requestFocus();
        // Faça aqui sua ação caso o campo esteja vazio.
    }
    if (!matcher.matches()) {
        editText.setError("Informe um CEP válido");
        editText.requestFocus();
        // Faça aqui sua ação caso seja o CEP invalido.
    } else {
        // Caso esteja tudo OK realize a ação aqui.
    }
```

Usando o REGEX que esta no pattern, caso queira outros formatos você pode procurar eles nesse site [aqui](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=CEP&c=-1&m=-1&ps=20).